# A simple ques-tion but I don't know why?

Tags: java

```
     public class Car2
          {
           int speed;
           String color;
           public static void main(String[]args)
                {
                     Car carpassedby=new Car();
                      carpassedby.speed=60;
                      carpassedby.color="green";
                }
           }
```

The IDE tell me the lastest "speed "  and "color " are error

Comment: Come on down voters, give this guy a break! He has limited English efficiency and hence the "poor" description, but otherwise it's a perfectly valid question. Or at least post the reason for your down votes.

Comment: In fact,even if I don't. Know how to vote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `Car2 carpassedby=new Car2();`. Your variables are in `Car2` but you are using `Car`.

Comment: Thanks a lot,P.S.   My English not good,Because I am a Chinese student.

Comment: no problem ,,, my english is not very good either .. coz i am bangladeshi :)